# Which Falcor router implementation are out there?

Tags: falcor, falcor-router

Is there any existing server-side implementation of Falcor route for various programming languages?

Answer (score 3):

**JavaScript**

So far besides the official:
https://github.com/Netflix/falcor-router-demo

I've found this one to be another good example:
https://github.com/tivac/falcor-experiment/

Comment: As a heads-up I'm transitioning my falcor-experiment to be a fully client-side router (because it's just wrapping up a REST API) in the not-too-distant future. My experiments w/ sever-side falcor routing will still be in the history though :)

Answer (score 2):

Although this is not a language, I'm working on a 'Model to Redis' implementation of the router.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/falcor-ioredis

This model:

```
{
    "somethingById": {
        "1": {
            "Foo": "Bar"
        },
        "2": {
            "Baz": "Baq"
        }
    }
}
```

Would be set in Redis as:

```
HSET somethingById 1 { "Foo": "Bar" }
HSET somethingById 2 { "Baz": "Baq" }
```

Comment: For those interested, did quite a big update on this package.

Answer (score 0):

**.NET**

For .NET Framework there is an implementation of the router [in progress].

https://github.com/pvasek/falcor-net

Also could be installed as a Nuget Package

```
Install-Package Falcor.Router.Owin
```